# Does clojure have raw string?

Tags: clojure, escaping, rawstring

In Python, I can prefix an `r` to a string literal (raw string) to tell the interpreter not translate special characters in the string:

```
>>> r"abc\nsdf#$%\^"
r"abc\nsdf#$%\^"
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Clojure?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Clojure strings are Java strings and the reader does not add anything significant to their interpretation. [The reader page](http://clojure.org/reader) just says "standard Java escape characters are supported."

You can escape the `\` though:

```
user> (print "abc\\nsdf#$%\\^")
abc\nsdf#$%\^
```

This only affect string literals read by the reader, so if you read strings from a file the reader never sees them:

```
user> (spit "/tmp/foo" "abc\\nsdf#$%\\^")
nil
user> (slurp "/tmp/foo")
"abc\\nsdf#$%\\^"
user> (print (slurp "/tmp/foo"))
abc\nsdf#$%\^nil
user>
```

So, I think the basic answer is no.

Answer (score 5):

Please also note that if you're using Counterclockwise (the Eclipse plugin for Clojure), there is a mode, called "smart paste" (disabled by default) which takes care of correctly escaping special characters when you paste inside an existing literal String.

Answer (score 4):

May be of use to a literal regular expression for such purposes.

```
user=> #"abc\nsdf#$%\^"
#"abc\nsdf#$%\^"
user=> (type #"abc\nsdf#$%\^")
java.util.regex.Pattern
user=> (println (str #"abc\nsdf#$%\^"))
abc\nsdf#$%\^
nil
```

Comment: Cheeky but worked perfectly to print some ascii art.