# Clojure Long Literal String

Tags: clojure

### What I want

Some programming languages have a feature for creating multi-line literal strings, for example:

```
some stuff ... <<EOF
  this is all part of the string
  as is this
  \ is a literal slash
  \n is a literal \ followed by a literal n
  the string ends on the next line
EOF
```

Question: Does Clojure have something similar to this? I realize that `"` handles multi-line fine, but I want it to also properly handle `\` as a literal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You might be interested in this little function.

```
(defn long-str [& strings] (clojure.string/join "\n" strings))
```

You'd use like so

```
(long-str "This is the first line. Implicitly I want a new line"
          "When I put a new line in the function call to create a new line")
```

This does require extra double quotes, but would be closer to what you want.

Comment: Why would you need to create a new function when there's `str`? E.g.,
`(str "Here is a line.\n"
      "And a second"
      "line.")`

Comment: @celwell to avoid having to explicitly include the new line character like in your example. Since the goal is to make a logical multi-line, \n is annoying. Clojure should support a `` style where it allows breaks across lines like in Go.

Answer (score 13):

If you need a `\` character in the string, just escape it. You don't have to do anything additional to support multiline strings, for example:

```
"hello \\
there \\
world "

=> "hello \\\nthere \\\nworld"
```

**EDIT :**

Now that you've clarified that you don't want to escape the `\` character, I'm afraid that Clojure doesn't offer a special syntax for escaping characters, this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043318/does-clojure-have-raw-string). In essence, Clojure deals with the same string syntax as Java, with no special syntax available.

Comment: The point is to not have to escape the \ character. I want a literal heredoc.

Comment: If you don't care about having to escape the \, then multi-line " already does what you seem to want.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to do this, put your literal string in a txt file and slurp it up with clojure.

```
(def my-string (slurp "super_long_string.txt"))
```

If you want to have it be hot-swappable, slurp it in a function.

```
(defn my-string [] (slurp "something.sql"))
```

This way every time you change the raw string, you automatically get its current value in your program by calling `(my-string)`.