# Literal string delimeters in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure

Does Clojure have anything like Python's """ as a delimiter for quoting large strings which can contains other quote marks?

I'm not seeing anything in the documentation but I'm surprised to use a modern language that only has a single way of delimiting strings.

Comment: [Clojure doesn't seem to have something like that unfortunately.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043318/does-clojure-have-raw-string)